# Macro for Iterator Loop for STL Iterables

Tags: c++, generics, stl, macros, iterator

### Concept

So, I'm trying to define a macro to simplify the following code:

```
for (vector<TYPE>::iterator iter = iterable.begin(); 
             iter != iterable.end(); iter++)
```

and

```
for (map<TYPE, TYPE>::iterator iter = iterable.begin();
             iter != iterable.end(); iter++)
```

etc.

### Existing Work

So far, I've got

```
#define every(iter, iterable) ::iterator iter = iterable.begin(); iter != iterable.end(); iter++
for (vector<TYPE> every(iter, iterable))
```

but I'd like to simplify this further.

### Goal

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do

```
for (every(iter, iterable))
```

which means that I'd need to somehow get the `class<TYPE>` of the iterable object. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

### Stipulations

- This, ideally, needs to go into a (relatively) large codebase already set up to access the `iterator` object.
- I am running on a compiler pre - C++11

### Victory

```
#define every(iter, iterable) typeof(iterable.begin()) iter = iterable.begin(); iter != iterable.end(); iter++
for (every(iter, iterable))
```

Comment: Can you use C++11 and `decltype`? If not, you can write a small trait class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer does *not* depend on C++11, but it needs `typeof`, which some compilers may not have. Should work with any recent g++

```
#define For(iter, iterable) for(typeof((iterable).begin()) iter = (iterable).begin(); iter != (iterable).end(); ++iter)
```

Comment: it's so straightforward, i missed it!

Comment: I did not know `typeof` could be used this way. +1

Comment: I think there are some limitations to `typeof`. If `f()` returns a reference type, such as `int&`, then (as far as I remember) `typeof(f())` is `int`, not `int&`. But it does a good job in the macro I just described.

Comment: Nice solution, although Ross' `for( auto& x : v )` would have my preference if the compiler supports it (i.e. you are using C++11).

Comment: You can now also use `auto` instead of `typeof` for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for(auto iter = iterable.being(); iter != iterable.end(); iter++)` if your compiler supports C++0x.

Comment: In C++0x one could use range-for instead. Also `++iter` is preferred in C++. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++11, you may use the new for syntax.

```
vector<double> v(9, 0.5);
auto total = 0.;
for (auto x: v) {
    total += x;
}
```

If you need a reference to modify the values, you may use:

```
vector<double> v(9, 0.5);
for (auto &x: v) {
    x = 5;
}
```

Just compile with the flag -std=c++0x.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using c++11 then use auto!

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++)
{
}
```

edit:

This would be your macro:

```
#define every(iter, iterable) auto iter = iterable.begin(); iter != iterable.end(); iter++
```

Then the implmentation:

```
for(every(iter, iterable))
{
    UseElement(*iter);
}
```

Comment: auto doesn't return an iterator properly (or at least, when I use auto, I get errors saying things like "no match for operator++ in TYPE")

Comment: it's identical. i'm under the impression that `auto` is doing something different, as i'm compiling with a pre - C++11 compiler

Comment: Ahh yeah it's a C++11 feature so that part would be important :)

Comment: In C++11 there wouldn't be any need for this macro. (Ideally, currently auto might be supported, but range-for not.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use std::for_each ? In C++11 you can use them with lambdas.

[C++11 also has a range base loop.](http://blog.knatten.org/2010/03/26/c0x-highlights-0-range-based-for-loop/)

```
template<typename T>
void Foo(const T& x)
{
    for (auto& i : x)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Of course the obligatory...**MACROS ARE EVIL**

If you are stuck with an ancient compiler you can always do

```
typedef std::map<int,int> IntMap_t;
IntMap_t tmap;
for( IntMap_t::iterator iter = tmap.begin();
         iter != tmap.end();
         ++iter)
{
}
```

Comment: if i could assume that `iterable` would be a `map<int, int>`, couldn't i just include that in the macro? unless `map<int, int>` is some sort of weird "universal iterable" in c++

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend Aaron McDaid's pretty nice answer. I had found very similar solution in **pre-C++0x** environment (I called the macro as `FOREACH`). It works for normal `iterator` and `reverse iterator`. But how could it be done on `const_iterator` and `const_reverse_iterator`? Unfortunately `cbegin()` is a C++0x feature, and `typeof(container)::const_iterator` does not work. A very small template class can solve the issue. Here is my code:

```
template <class T>
struct IterType { typedef typename T::const_iterator citer_t; };

#define FOREACHCONST(_CIter, _Container) \
  for(IterType<typeof(_Container)>::citer_t _CIter = (_Container).begin(); \
      _CIter != (_Container).end(); ++_CIter )
```

It works exactly on the same way as `FOREACH`.

Interestingly this does not work inside a templated function. In that case the `typename` keyword has to be added right before `IterType`, but in that case it cannot used outside a templated function.